# Hibernate dialect for Oracle12c

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle12c

I am working in application using Hibernate(3.5.3), JPA and Java 7.

which hibernate dialect can be used for Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle10gDialect goes fine with oracle 10g and above

Answer (score 0):

I was using the following dialect for my application (JPA, Oracle DB 12c & above, Spring 2.5.6) and it works very well when configured in application.properties

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect